# Group points in an array to perform operations on the whole group

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scipy, scikit-image

I'm currently trying to make a program that takes a binary color image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/evmjG.jpg) and tells if any of the white dots are "covered" by something (i.e. some of the points that I tell the program should be white end up black in the image). As requested, here's the original image as well (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pClJL.jpg). It's just some LEDs shining through holes. I've done that using the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('bwimg.jpg')
pixels = np.asarray(img)
pixels = np.nonzero(pixels)
xpixels = pixels[1] # x coordinate of each white pixel
ypixels = pixels[0] # y coordinate of each white pixel

# example estimations for the center coordinates of some of the points (can be calibrated further, just an example)
xcoords = [60, 160, 255, 350, 445]
ycoords = [410, 405, 400, 395, 390]

for coo in range(0,4):
   indexList = np.ravel(np.asarray(xpixels == xcoords[coo]).nonzero())
   for y in range(0,4):
      for x in indexList:
         if ypixels[x] == ycoords[y]:
            print(x, xcoords[coo], ycoords[y])
```

This works to a point, but I'd like to make it so that it won't fail if some of the white points are only half-covered by something, or if some piece of debris falls on a dot and a couple points are accidentally colored black.

So, instead of just taking a point from the middle of the white dot, doing something like "say the white dot is 'uncovered' if more than 50% of pixels in x radius are white." I'm thinking I could do something like that with opencv or maybe scipy, but I have no idea what. Any help would be much appreciated!

p.s. I don't post on here much, so I'm not really sure if its okay to add the 'scipy' tag since it isn't really *about* scipy. If it isn't let me know and I'll remove it.

Comment: It would help if you can explain your problem using the original image

Comment: I added the original image. I'm not sure it really helps much, it's just some LEDs shining up toward the camera.